# Valid JSON with Angular Scope Object variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-http

Good afternoon S.O. gurus. Its my first time using AngularJS' $http.post and I understand I have to create a variable to save the body of data Im passing before hand, so I created the following:

```
var data = {
        "users": [
                {
                "requestId": val,
                "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "First Name",
                    "value": $scope.FirstName
                },
                {
                    "name": "Middle Name",
                    "value": $scope.MiddleInitial
                },
                {
                    "name": "Last Name",
                    "value": $scope.LastName
                },
                {
                    "name": "Role",
                    "value": "Contractor"
                },
                {
                    "name": "usr_manager_key",
                    "value": "10001"
                },
                    {
                    "name": "MANAGEDSERVICE",
                    "value": "Yes"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Job Title",
                    "value": $scope.JobTitle
                },
                {
                    "name": "Start Date",
                    "value": $scope.SelectedStartTotal
                },
                {
                    "name": "End Date",
                    "value": $scope.SelectedEndTotal
                },
                {
                    "name": "DOB_DAY_HASH",
                    "value": $scope.SelectedDOBDay
                },
                {
                    "name": "NATIONAL_ID_HASH",
                    "value": $scope.SSN
                },
                {
                    "name": "act_key",
                    "value": 1
                }
            ]
  }]
};
```

Keep in mind that all these values are coming from ng-models on the views in a form, and the whole section is wrapped in its own Controller. The code you see is within that controller.

My issue is that its erroring out my code and not returning as valid JSON. Can you assist please? Is this not valid JSON and I'm just having a noob moment? Apologies if this is mundane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "requestId": val , val in your 4th line and I dont think you can something like this

```
{
  "name": "First Name",
  "value": $scope.FirstName // this is what I dont think can happen
}
```

for this you can do it like this: `data.users[0].fields[0].value = $scope.FirstName`

Comment: val is a variable I assigned to generate a random 4 digit number. I'll try that method for the $scope.FirstName

Comment: first try to make small JSON data and then do what u want when it works

Comment: I've marked the answer, but I dont have enough rep to upvote :(

Comment: @Adro , okay good luck for future and welcome to angularJS/Angular World